# Swift: how to disable MapKit annotation's info button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, mapkit

When I create a MapKit annotation it has a default "i" button. How to disable this button or make a new segue?[image]

Comment: anything you did try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` then make sure the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` is nil